# data.table with Specific criterias - R

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I have this kind of dataset

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                 disease = c(A, B, B, C, D, A, B, B), 
                 date = c("2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-03", "2020-02-02", "2011-01-01"))
```

These three ID's have different diseases/diagnosis given on the SAME date.
I need a finish dataset that is based on this criteria:
If an ID have two different diseases on the SAME date, then choose the disease that has the highest priority.
The priority list is: A, B, C, D

Another case (ID 4): has the same disease on two DIFFERENT date. The criteria here should be. If an ID have the SAME disease on DIFFERENT DATES, then choose the first in time.

so the final output would look like this:

```
ID  disease  date
1     A      2020-03-02
2     B      2020-03-01
3     A      2020-03-03
4     B      2011-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the diseases to an index based on priority. Second, sort the table by ID, then priority, then date. Finally, use a grouping operation to get the first row by ID.

```
priority <- LETTERS[1:4]
setorder(dt[, disease2 := match(disease, priority)], ID, disease2, date)[, .SD[1], ID, .SDcols = 2:3][]
#>    ID disease       date
#> 1:  1       A 2020-03-02
#> 2:  2       B 2020-03-01
#> 3:  3       A 2020-03-03
#> 4:  4       B 2011-01-01
```

Comment: What if  the disease are not letters but instead "abc", "dcd", "dse", "sss"

Comment: `priority` can be any character vector you want. Ideally it would contain the unique values in `dt$disease`.

Answer (score 2):

**option 1**

```
setkey(dt, ID, disease, date)
dt[, .SD[1], ID]
```

**option 2**

```
dt[order(ID, disease, date), .SD[1], ID]
```

**results**

```
   ID disease       date
1:  1       A 2020-03-02
2:  2       B 2020-03-01
3:  3       A 2020-03-03
4:  4       B 2011-01-01
```

Note that if you want ***another priority order*** you can add this line to make disease an ordered factor first.

```
dt[, disease := ordered(disease, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "A"))]
```

Using one of the two given options it then returns

```
   ID disease       date
1:  1       B 2020-03-02
2:  2       B 2020-03-01
3:  3       D 2020-03-03
4:  4       B 2011-01-01
```

Comment: Or, you can try `setorder(dt)[, .SD[1], ID]` for shorter.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, nice addition and yes that would do if the order criteria are the same as the column order, which is indeed the case here.

Comment: It doesnt work if my order criteria is different - lets say the order is B, C, D, A?